# Integer.valueOf not working for binary representation of -1 in Java

Tags: java, math, integer, bit

The following code attempts to output to obtain -1 from its 2's complement binary representation, but gives a NumberFormatException.

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(-1), 2));  //Raises Exception

System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2));  //Raises Exception
```

Infact Integer.valueOf doesn't seem to work for any signed negative number's binary representation. Why is the code outputting error?

Comment: How is `valueOf` supposed to know that is a binary number, much less a 2's compliment one?

Comment: x86 processors and modern programming languages use 2's complement system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Comment: @ScottHunter The valueOf's second argument takes the radix, so is it not supposed to know? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`valueOf` doesn't know about 2's complement, so it thinks you are asking to covert an unsigned value in base 2 that is too large to fit in an int.  (Try removing one of the `1`'s.)

Comment: Oh. So, valueOf treats the binary representation as a unsigned integer (with the exception of last bit)?

Comment: @user85421: That means it will consider the value as negative *if you include a negative sign*.

Comment: I think the document would have been more clear if they had specified it explicitly, rather than giving some examples (which they have given below).

Comment: @user85421: Missed the reference to the author.